# Missing property exception when using file upload

Tags: grails

When testing upload function from postman throws an                            ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [POST] /api/uploadExcel - parameters:
Error msg: Cannot get property 'bytes' on null object.

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

class testController {


     def upload()
     {
       try
        {
           MultipartFile file = request.getFile('file')
           println("Info:"+file);       //file returns null
        }

       catch (Exception e)
       {
        System.out.println ("Error msg: " + e.getMessage());
        println("Fail status:"+e.StackTrace);
       }
     }
```

From the postman sending the same filename but still it fails.

Comment: Are you sending the file name as `file` ? If not you have to because in your controller code you have accessed the file with name as `file` from request.

Comment: Yes Prakash i did.I am passing the same file name.